# function returning a string of zeros in c

Tags: c

i trying to create a function that return an array of zeros us a char array 
and print this array in a file text but when i return a string an addition char was returned

[image]

this the text file string the program wrote

[image]

this my fuction :

```
 char *zeros_maker (int kj,int kj1)
{
     char *zeros;
    zeros = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(kj-kj1));
    int i;
    for(i =0;i<kj-kj1;i++)
        zeros[i]='0';
    printf("%s\n",zeros);
    return zeros;
}
```

the instruction i used when i printed in the file

```
fprintf(pFile,"%c%s%c &",34,zeros_maker(added_zeros,0),34);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A *string* in C ends with a `0` byte (**value** `0`, not the character `'0'`). So, what you construct here is *not a string*. Your usage is a memory leak.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: your code as it's currently written has a memory leak as you don't `free` the memory allocated in your function

Comment: @ChrisTurner but that is the intention of the program? To return a string of zeroes?\

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think you're confusing program with function? The function returns allocated memory but in the example use-case it's passed straight to `fprintf` so there is no way the program could free it.

Comment: Using 34 in place of `'"'` is obfuscatory.  Using the character literal, please.  As shown, you leak memory — irrecoverably.  You can't afford to do that in production code.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` in C is the value of the encoding used for the digit zero. This is not *allowed* to have the value 0 by the C standard.

You need to add a NUL-terminator `'\0'` to the end of the `char` array, in order for the `printf` function to work correctly.

Else you run the risk of it running past the end of the `char` array, with undefined results.

Finally, don't forget to `free` the allocated memory at some point in your program.

Comment: It working when i'm adding the terminator thanks a lot

Comment: @Mourad: Naturally!

Comment: Given the call `zeros_maker(added_zeros, 0)`, if `added_zeros` is, for sake of discussion, 6, then the code allocates 6 bytes for the 6 zeros.  There isn't room for the null byte.  The memory allocation needs to be 'hi - lo + 1` (or, in terms of the implementation, `kj - kj1 + 1`.  And the example usage is an unavoidable memory leak.  The return value of the function must be saved, and the pointer passed to `printf()` and then to `free()`: `char *tmp = zeros_maker(added_zeros, 0); printf("%c%s%c &", '"', tmp, '"'); free(tmp);`.

Answer (score 0):

[**Read about how string in `C` are meant to be terminated**](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html).

Each string terminates with the `null` char `'\0'` (the NULL symbol ASCII value 0, not to be confused with the char `'0'` that has ASCII value `48`). **It identifies the end of the string**.

```
zeros[kj-kj1]='\0';
```

Plus check always if you are accessing an element out of bound. In this case it happens if `kj1> kj`

Comment: it's working when i'm adding the terminator thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for loop, you may get hand of `memset`.

```
char* zeros_maker(int kj,int kj1)
{
    int len=kj-kj1;
    char *zeros=malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
    memset(zeros,'0',len-1);
    zeros[len-1]=0;
    printf("%s\n",zeros);
    //fflush(stdout);
    return zeros;
}
```

Or if you are not fan of C-style string, and it's going to be ASCII only, following could be used too. Just be careful what your are doing this way.

```
char* zeros_maker_pascal_form(int kj,int kj1)
{
    int len=kj-kj1;
    char *zeros=malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
    memset(zeros,'0',len);
    for(int a=0;a<len;a++){
      printf("%c",zeros[a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //fflush(stdout);
    return zeros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few basic issues, the main one is that it fails to terminate the string (and include space for the terminator).

Here's a fixed and cleaned-up version:

```
char * zeros_maker(size_t length)
{
  char *s = malloc(length + 1);
  if(s != NULL)
  {
    memset(s, '0', length);
    s[length - 1] = '\0';
  }
  return s;
}
```

This has the following improvements over your code:

- It simplifies the interface, just taking the number of zeroes that should be returned (the length of the returned string). Do the subtraction at the call site, where those two values make sense.
- No cast of the return value from `malloc()`, and no scaling by `sizeof (char)` since I consider that pointless.
- Check for `NULL` being returned by `malloc()` before using the memory.
- Use `memset()` to set a range of bytes to a single value, that's a standard C function and much easier to know and verify than a custom loop.
- Terminate the string, of course.

Call it like so:

```
char *zs = zeros_maker(kj - kj1);
puts(s);
free(s);
```

Remember to `free()` the string once you're done with it.